# How to make Woocommerce checkout page fields to read-only

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

For edit `woocommerce` (WordPressss plugin) account page fields and make to read-only, easy edit `woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php` file and only add **read-only** to end of fields tags end (sorry my English and programming is not professional and good)

But for edit `woocommerce` checkout page fields and make one, or two and more fields, for example, email field, to read-only, cannot do the previous way

Please help me to do it, I have not idea.

It would be much better if, teach me to do it from functions.php easy and better and durable way (if it is possible).

thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in your theme's "function.php" file.

```
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
        function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
                if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2'){
                    $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
                    if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                        $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
                    }
                }
            }
            return $checkout_fields;
        }
```

This function will check if the address fields have value (i.e. if the address is specified), and if it has value, makes the field/s readonly. Else keeps the fields open to add data for the user. You can apply the same concept for each required fields.

Hope this helps.

Thank You!

Comment: very thank you for answer mr amritosh pandey this code work correctly.
i post new question below my first question. If possible for you , answer too my new question
again and more thank you for.

Comment: yes, i've posted my +vote. but not see my aded vote to your answer after refresh the page!
received below notification after post my vote:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

very thank you for answer mr amritosh pandey
this code work correctly

for only email field , remove:

```
if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2'){
```

and i change to

```
if($key == 'billing_email'){
```

and work perfect and correctly

my new queston is > if use for two field , example: mobile (tel) and email or more field
Should i repeat all codes?
from add_action to return $checkout_fields; }

or can repeat
if($key line 2 or 3 or more?

example:

```
...
...
if($key == 'billing_email'){
if($key == 'billing_phone'){
if($key == 'billing_postcode'){
...
...
```

thank you

Comment: You can use OR condition in the code for multiple fields. For example -

 ` if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2' || $key == 'billing_email' || $key == 'billing_phone' || $key == 'billing_postcode'){ `

Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: you are the best, this also work fine and correctly, very thank you @amritosh-pandey